# How can I insert a row for each day within a date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table and every row will have an `ID`, `Date`, and `Value` column. I want it so that every time a person accesses a page on my web site, a stored procedure will run that will insert a row for each day within a range IF that day doesn't already exist.

The date range will be from 01/01/2012 until the Saturday before the current day (the day the page was accessed). The `ID` will auto-generate and the `Value` field will remain NULL/blank.

For example, if I accessed the page today, I would want a record in the table for every day between 01/01/2012 until 03/03/2012.

Comment: Just create a loop in your stored proc.

Comment: @Daniel there are definitely more elegant solutions than loops.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I assumed that, that's why I just posted it as a comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets all the days that don't exist yet, and excludes rows after the previous Saturday.

```
;WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (366) d = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id), '20111231')
  FROM sys.all_objects
)
INSERT dbo.[a table]([Date])
  SELECT d FROM d 
  WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.[a table])
  AND d <= DATEADD(DAY, 0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE());
```

Note that I assumed you would "reset" this once your calendar year rolled over.

Comment: If the page is hit on a Saturday, I want to get the previous Saturday.  I don't care if it's 11:59:59pm on that Saturday, I want to retrieve the previous Saturday.

Comment: The additional WHERE clause I added does this. If you hit the page on 3/3 it will only return up to 2/25.